# Tengo un problema con mi recyclerview en mi fragment

Tags: android-fragment, recyclerview, android-recyclerview

El problema de mi recyclerview en mi fragment es un error muy tonto por que me equivoque en el nombre de una variable una disculpa.

Comment: En ese caso, por favor elimina la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: o recupérala y publica una respuesta con la solución

Comment: Si la resolviste y quieres aportar a la comunidad, redacta una respuesta siguiendo [answer]. Si no, borra la pregunta. Un saludo